What does Plain text e-mail document checkbox in Microsoft Word refer to?
Screenshot of AutoFormat DiagWhat does the Plain text e-mail documents refer to in Microsoft Word 2021?  What does it do, and what is it used for?
I also notice that Outlook has the exact same setting.  How would would this setting apply to MS Word.
The setting is located under autocorrect > AutoFormat.
